# Repeat block of code using While or For loop

Tags: python, loops

Here is the chunk of code i need to repeat im using python v3.4 for all of it

```
    x = input ("Username: ")
    if x == "reed":
        f1 = input ("password: ")
        if f1 == "reed1":
            m = input ("hello reed how may i assist you today: Settings, File Directory: ")
            if m == "Settings":
                print ("Loading Settings")
                m3 = input ("Internet, Update, Sound: ")
                if m3 == "Internet":
                    n3 = input (": ")
                elif m3 == "Update":
                    n7 = input (": ")
                elif m3 == "Sound":
                    n8 = input (": ")
           elif m == "File Directory":
               print ("Loading File Directory")
               m2 = input ("C:, D:, Program Files: ")
               if m2 == "C:":
                   input ("type file name.ext: ")
               elif m2 == "D:":
                   m3 = input ("type file name.ext: ")
           if m3 == "poem":
                poem_1 = open ("C:\Python34\poems\The Friend.txt")
                print(poem_1.read(500000))
                poem_1.close()
           elif m2 == "Program Files":
                ba = input ("type file name.ext: ")
else:
    print ("incorrect password continuing program")
```

what i need is to repeat this block of code until otherwise but the while statement is useless it only repeats the first line and i couldnt use the for statement. now im only typing to waste space so it will let me post

Comment: Your code is not complete. Give us a complete minimal working example.

Comment: Folks play nice! A complete newcomer doesn't deserve a down vote welcome, even if his question is off tangent!

Comment: @jjlittels: Shorten your code. Make a function out of it. Do not post more than 20 lines.

Comment: To clean up your code, you can build a dictionary for all the choices and then access the right entry without all those ifs. For example, `choice = {"file directory": {"C": {"read me": "README.txt", "soldiers of time": "poems/Soldiers of Time.txt", "father": "poems/Father.txt"}}}` and `home_dir = "C:/Python34".` So in the case for `m` being `"file directory"`, you ask for `m2` and `ba` and then `f = home_dir + choice[m][m2][ba]` will always be the file, for example "C:/Python34/README.txt".

Comment: I just started using python a few weeks ago for a school project and i need to be able to loop back to the top of this chunk if necessary but everything ive tried just does either the first statement or gives an error

Comment: Indentation is critical in python. Are you sure you have indented your code properly? You have `if password == "reed"` and `else: print ("incorrect password continuing program")` at the different indentation depths. Also, what is the condition you want to be met to break the loop? What error do you get and what have you tried to get such an error?

Comment: Its not indented right because of the way this post entry works i tried but its weird and im noob, I want a question to be 
x = input ("would you like to go back: ")
if x == "yes":
go back: whatever command works here
else:
continue program

Comment: and i just found an answer in a dusty hidden site in the bowels on the internet sorry for wasting all of your time

Answer (score 3):

Breaking things out into functions really helps to clean up code. I'd suggest giving your variables meaningful names as well (e.g. `user` instead of `x`).

I've eliminated some of your code that wasn't necessary to give you a picture of one way you could go about it. There are probably many other (*better*) ways to go about this.

---

I started off by defining a few functions to handle repeated tasks at the top of the file.

```
def Login():
    user = input("Username: ")
    password = input("password: ")
    return user == "reed" and password == "reed1"

def DoSettings():
    print("Loading Settings")
    subcommand = input("Internet, Update, Sound: ")
    if subcommand == "Internet":
        print("Internet is broken!")
    elif subcommand == "Update":
        print("Ambiguous update... updating all the things!!!")
    elif subcommand == "Sound":
        print("Beep beep!")

def DoFileDirectory():
    print("Doing file stuff")
```

I then followed this up with the main loop of the program. I'm assuming you just need to login once, so that's outside of the loop. After that it'll loop until you type `Quit`.

```
if not Login():
    print("Hey! You're not reed!")
    exit()

MAIN_PROMPT = "Hi reed, how may I assist you today? Settings, File Directory, Quit: "
command = input(MAIN_PROMPT)
while not command == "Quit":
    if command == "Settings":
        DoSettings()
    elif command == "File Directory":
        DoFileDirectory()
    else:
        print("Unrecognized command")
    command = input(MAIN_PROMPT)

print("Goodbye!~")
```